# How to get data with data

Tags: regex

I try to get blocks with this regex `.*[%].*(?:.*|(?:\n.+)*)`.

I want to get lines which contains `%` operator like below :

```
Match 1:
Test14%=SN54LS161AJ=U14, 

Match 2:
U15%=123131CCC11=U15, LOGIC , ---, 40394 
[Unit] = 
[Diag] = Tests ERROR

Match 3:
P10%=SN54LS161AJ=U14, LOGIC , ---, 40734 

Match 4:
X10%=123C11=U15, LO
[Unit] = 
[Diag] = Tests ERROR 70

Match 5:
N20%=SN54LS161AJ=U14, LO

Match 6:
N20%=123C11=N20
[Unit] = 
[Diag] = Tests ERROR 2
```

I try here by an example : https://regex101.com/r/BPLJlJ/1

Comment: Try `^[^%\n]*%.*(?:\n[^%\n]+$)*`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VHoy5P/1).

Comment: You could also make it a bit more specific `^[^\r\n%]*\d%=.*(?:\r?\n\[[^][\r\n]*].*)*` https://regex101.com/r/EtI1LO/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried, this part `(?:\n.+)*` will not be evaluated as the first alternative `.*` will always match and only a single line will be matched.

You could update the pattern to

```
[^\r\n%]*%.*(?:\n.+)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uz05s8/1)

Or a bit more specific pattern might be:

```php
^[^\r\n%]*\d%=.*(?:\r?\n\[[^][\r\n]*].*)*
```

- `^[^\r\n%]*` Match any char except a newline or `%`
- `\d%=.*` Match a digit, `%=` and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n`
  - `\[[^][\r\n]*].*` Match from `[...]` and the rest of the line
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat it

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EtI1LO/1)